Align 2 sets of 3D points in Unity and 3D Landmarks from Python
I'm having a set of 3D Points that I have used python to measure them from an SMPL mesh https://smpl-x.is.tue.mpg.de/
I have done several calculations using https://github.com/DavidBoja/SMPL-Anthropometry
The result mesh is shown here:

I exported those Landmarks shown in json. My Plan is to do an AR world in Unity and at least show those landmarks correctly there, by showing I mean transform it. For that I used Mediapipe in Unity to again detect the 3D Keypoints, and I have used SVD to transform the points. But the resultant points are transformed to wrong positions in the scene.
 "measurement_points": {
    "HEAD_TOP": [
      -0.035465046763420105,
      -1.0376317501068115,
      -0.09636712819337845
    ],
    "HEAD_LEFT_TEMPLE": [
      0.05162014067173004,
      -0.9864024519920349,
      -0.05941466987133026
    ],
    "NECK_ADAM_APPLE": [
      -0.011730188503861427,
      -0.7966534495353699,
      -0.10268360376358032
    ],
    "LEFT_HEEL": [
      0.14228636026382446,
      0.4532795548439026,
      0.34400951862335205
    ],
    "RIGHT_HEEL": [
      -0.07070167362689972,
      0.465068519115448,
      0.2884930372238159
    ],
    "LEFT_NIPPLE": [
      0.08982982486486435,
      -0.6190084218978882,
      -0.11780978739261627
    ],
    "RIGHT_NIPPLE": [
      -0.08163388073444366,
      -0.6134512424468994,
      -0.13753655552864075
    ],
    "SHOULDER_TOP": [
      -0.009784799069166183,
      -0.7803500890731812,
      -0.08618584275245667
    ],
    "INSEAM_POINT": [
      0.008008850738406181,
      -0.1900506615638733,
      -0.07737725973129272
    ],
    "BELLY_BUTTON": [
      0.010561510920524597,
      -0.36784613132476807,
      -0.10724663734436035
    ],
    "BACK_BELLY_BUTTON": [
      -0.00937563180923462,
      -0.4537953734397888,
      0.08685334026813507
    ],
    "CROTCH": [
      0.004702351056039333,
      -0.1561068892478943,
      0.012684870511293411
    ],
    "PUBIC_BONE": [
      0.009052575565874577,
      -0.22637012600898743,
      -0.08407296985387802
    ],
    "RIGHT_WRIST": [
      -0.3712169826030731,
      -0.9884175062179565,
      -0.31503304839134216
    ],
    "LEFT_WRIST": [
      0.39843985438346863,
      -0.38807734847068787,
      0.04636390507221222
    ],
    "RIGHT_BICEP": [
      -0.26270052790641785,
      -0.7314295768737793,
      -0.14423565566539764
    ],
    "RIGHT_FOREARM": [
      -0.3548571765422821,
      -0.8156181573867798,
      -0.23603355884552002
    ],
    "LEFT_SHOULDER": [
      0.14071761071681976,
      -0.7944884300231934,
      0.024217886850237846
    ],
    "RIGHT_SHOULDER": [
      -0.154975026845932,
      -0.7946627736091614,
      -0.03227522224187851
    ],
    "LOW_LEFT_HIP": [
      0.09775020182132721,
      -0.19370722770690918,
      -0.056613221764564514
    ],
    "LEFT_THIGH": [
      0.0889224261045456,
      -0.037434935569763184,
      -0.026097871363162994
    ],
    "LEFT_CALF": [
      0.10497565567493439,
      0.23177915811538696,
      0.1475173979997635
    ],
    "LEFT_ANKLE": [
      0.11254105716943741,
      0.3804142475128174,
      0.2514151334762573
    ],
    "HEELS": [
      0.03579234331846237,
      0.4591740369796753,
      0.316251277923584
    ]
  },

The result of the transformed points in the scene they are marked with green spheres

The code that I did for that:
public class SMPLMediaPipeMapper : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextAsset smplDataJson;
    private JObject smplData;
    private Vector3[] smplJoints;
    private Dictionary<int, int> smplToMediaPipeMapping;
    private Dictionary<string, Vector3> measurementPoints;
    private Camera mainCamera;

    public Vector3[] mediaPipeKeypoints;
    public float mediaPipeToSMPLScale = 1f;
    public Vector3 mediaPipeToSMPLOffset = Vector3.zero;

    public GameObject jointSpherePrefab;
    public GameObject measurementPointPrefab;

    private bool measurementPointsInstantiated = false;
    private Matrix4x4 transformationMatrix;

    void Start()
    {
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
        LoadSMPLData();
    }

    void LoadSMPLData()
    {
        smplData = JObject.Parse(smplDataJson.text);

        var jointsValues = smplData["smpl_joints"].ToObject<List<List<float>>>();
        smplJoints = jointsValues.Select(j => new Vector3(j[0], j[1], j[2])).ToArray();

        smplToMediaPipeMapping = smplData["smpl_to_mediapipe_mapping"].ToObject<Dictionary<int, int>>();

        measurementPoints = smplData["measurement_points"]
            .ToObject<Dictionary<string, List<float>>>()
            .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => new Vector3(kvp.Value[0], kvp.Value[1], kvp.Value[2]));
    }
    Quaternion CalculateRotation(List<Vector3> sourcePoints, List<Vector3> targetPoints)
    {
        if (sourcePoints.Count != targetPoints.Count)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Source and target points must have the same number of elements.");
        }

        // Create matrices for source and target points
        var sourceMatrix = DenseMatrix.Create(sourcePoints.Count, 3, 0.0);
        var targetMatrix = DenseMatrix.Create(targetPoints.Count, 3, 0.0);

        for (int i = 0; i < sourcePoints.Count; i++)
        {
            sourceMatrix[i, 0] = sourcePoints[i].x;
            sourceMatrix[i, 1] = sourcePoints[i].y;
            sourceMatrix[i, 2] = sourcePoints[i].z;
            targetMatrix[i, 0] = targetPoints[i].x;
            targetMatrix[i, 1] = targetPoints[i].y;
            targetMatrix[i, 2] = targetPoints[i].z;
        }

        // Compute the covariance matrix
        var covarianceMatrix = targetMatrix.Transpose() * sourceMatrix;

        // Perform SVD
        var svd = covarianceMatrix.Svd();
        var u = svd.U;
        var vt = svd.VT;

        // Calculate the rotation matrix
        var rotationMatrix = vt * u.Transpose();

        // Convert rotation matrix to quaternion
        Vector3 columnZ = new Vector3((float)rotationMatrix[0, 2], (float)rotationMatrix[1, 2], (float)rotationMatrix[2, 2]);
        Vector3 columnY = new Vector3((float)rotationMatrix[0, 1], (float)rotationMatrix[1, 1], (float)rotationMatrix[2, 1]);
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(columnZ, columnY);

        // Ensure a proper rotation (det(U) should be 1)
        if (Mathf.Sign(Quaternion.Dot(rotation, Quaternion.identity)) < 0)
        {
            rotation = new Quaternion(-rotation.x, -rotation.y, -rotation.z, -rotation.w);
        }

        return rotation;
    }


    void CalculateTransformationMatrix()
    {
        if (mediaPipeKeypoints == null || mediaPipeKeypoints.Length < 33)
        {
            Debug.LogError("MediaPipe keypoints not initialized or have insufficient points.");
            return;
        }

        List<Vector3> sourcePoints = new List<Vector3>();
        List<Vector3> targetPoints = new List<Vector3>();

        foreach (var kvp in smplToMediaPipeMapping)
        {
            if (kvp.Key < smplJoints.Length && kvp.Value < mediaPipeKeypoints.Length)
            {
                sourcePoints.Add(smplJoints[kvp.Key]);
                targetPoints.Add(mediaPipeKeypoints[kvp.Value]);
            }
        }

        Vector3 centroidSource = CalculateCentroid(sourcePoints);
        Vector3 centroidTarget = CalculateCentroid(targetPoints);

        List<Vector3> centeredSource = CenterPoints(sourcePoints, centroidSource);
        List<Vector3> centeredTarget = CenterPoints(targetPoints, centroidTarget);

        Quaternion rotation = CalculateRotation(centeredSource, centeredTarget);
        Vector3 translation = centroidTarget - rotation * centroidSource;

        transformationMatrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(translation, rotation, Vector3.one);
        mediaPipeToSMPLScale = CalculateScale(sourcePoints, targetPoints);
        mediaPipeToSMPLOffset = translation;
    }

    Vector3 CalculateCentroid(List<Vector3> points)
    {
        return points.Aggregate(Vector3.zero, (sum, p) => sum + p) / points.Count;
    }

    List<Vector3> CenterPoints(List<Vector3> points, Vector3 centroid)
    {
        return points.Select(p => p - centroid).ToList();
    }
     
    float CalculateScale(List<Vector3> sourcePoints, List<Vector3> targetPoints)
    {
        float sourceScale = sourcePoints.Select(p => p.magnitude).Average();
        float targetScale = targetPoints.Select(p => p.magnitude).Average();
        return targetScale / sourceScale;
    }

    public void UpdateMediaPipeKeypoints(Vector3[] newKeypoints)
    {
        if (newKeypoints.Length != 33)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Expected 33 MediaPipe keypoints");
            return;
        }
        mediaPipeKeypoints = newKeypoints;
        CalculateTransformationMatrix();
        VisualizeMappedKeypoints();
        //VisualizeMeasurementPoints();
    }

    Vector3 TransformPoint(Vector3 point, bool inverse = false)
    {
        return inverse
            ? transformationMatrix.inverse.MultiplyPoint3x4(point)
            : transformationMatrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(point);
    }

    public Vector3[] GetMappedSMPLKeypoints()
    {
        return smplJoints.Select(j => TransformPoint(j)).ToArray();
    }

    public void VisualizeMappedKeypoints()
    {
        if (measurementPointsInstantiated) return;

        UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Enqueue(() =>
        {
            foreach (var kvp in smplToMediaPipeMapping)
            {
                if (kvp.Key < smplJoints.Length && kvp.Value < mediaPipeKeypoints.Length)
                {
                    Vector3 mappedPoint = TransformPoint(smplJoints[kvp.Key]);
                    GameObject sphere = Instantiate(jointSpherePrefab, mappedPoint, Quaternion.identity, transform);
                    sphere.name = $"MappedJoint_{kvp.Key}";
                }
            }
            measurementPointsInstantiated = true;
        });
    }
 


The approach I know of for this is called "Iterative closest point" or ICP. I don't think an SVD is enough, but I don't really understand the underlying math.

@JonasH So you are considering those landmarks points from Python generated(mesh), to MediaPipe 3D Keypoints as point cloud ?

@JonasH but for example the landmarks in python are less than in terms of numbers than the media key points(33points). How can ICP would help in that

In my use case we just used a random subset of points. But this was with 10-100k points. You could probably also just select the closest N points in each iteration.  There might be reasons ICP is not useful for your use case, but I wanted to mention the algorithm so you can do further evaluation.
